# Google Drive API v3 - Files List returns old information

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using an application that modifies the *properties* field of my [Drive Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) using the Google Drive API v3 [Files Update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method. Let's say I have a file with a "test" property with the value "my first value". Then, I update the file specifying the file ID and sending an object in the request body with the properties to be updated as the following:

```
{
 "properties": {
    "test": "some random value"
  }
}
```

The API returns a 200, so the file has been successfully updated. Then, the application sends a request to the [Files List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method to list the files for the parent folder, and the file I just updated still has "my first value" in the "test" property.

However, if I send a request to the [Files Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method, passing the file ID, the properties object has the "test" property with the value updated ("some random value").

What am I missing? Why does the Files List method return obsolete information?

You can replicate this scenario using the *Try it!* section of each method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I update the property and the file is retrieved using the method of "Files: list", the updated property can be seen. I apologize for this. For example, after you updated the property, when you run the method of "Files: list" several times, what result will you obtain?

Comment: When I list the files after the update, I obtain the document with the "old" information (property not updated). However, using "Files: get" I obtain the document with up-to-date information. After a few minutes, the "Files: list" method returns the document information updated (property with the new value). Also, it does not always happen, it's just an inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Also, it does not always happen, it's just an inconsistent behavior.`, how about reporting it to the Google issue tracker? https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: Thanks, will do.